# впечатления почему пишется а

Tags: орфография, словообразование, морфемика, удвоенные-буквы, существительные

Помогите разобраться со словом **растерянность**.

- Как оно разбирается по составу (суффиксы: **-я-нн-ость**, **-янн-ость** или **-я-нность**)?
- Согласно какому правилу в слове *растерянность* пишется два **н**?
- Словообразование: образовано от слова *растерянный* или *растеряться* (или другой вариант)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***растерянность***… образовано от слова *растерянный* или *растеряться*?

Словообразовательная цепочка:

растеря-**нн**(ый) (прич.) -> растерянн(ый) (переход прич. в прил.) -> растерянн-**ость**;

> Как оно разбирается по составу

**рас/тер/я/нн/ость/+нулевое окончание**

> Почему в слове *растерянный* два ***н***?

См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=53#pp53 :

> **§ 98…**
>
> <...>
>
> 2. Пишутся также с ***нн*** причастия не на *-ованный (-ёванный, -еванный)* глаголов совершенного вида и соотносительные с ними прилагательные; подавляющее большинство таких глаголов содержит
>      приставку...

===

> Согласно какому правилу в слове *растерянность* пишется два ***н***?

Из книги "Русское письмо в правилах с комментариями" (авторы -- Е.В. Бешенкова, О.Е. Иванова; М., 2011):

> В существительных на ***-ость***, производных от прилагательных с
>   ***нн***, пишется ***нн***… В существительных на ***-ость***, производных от прилагательных с ***н***, пишется одно ***н***…
>
> Правило можно сформулировать и по-другому:
>
> В словах на ***-ость*** после гласных пишется ***нн***, кроме
>   *ветреность, леность*, после согласных -- одно ***н.***

Можно сослаться и на ПАС (http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=55#pp55 ):

> **§ 105.** Наречия на ***-о***, **существительные** с суффиксами ***-ость, -ик, -иц(а)***, образованные от прилагательных и страдательных причастий, пишутся с двойным ***н*** или одним ***н*** —
>   в зависимости от того, как пишется соответствующее прилагательное или
>   причастие.

Comment: У вас: растеряться - растерянный (прич.). Но причастия образуются от ПЕРЕХОДНЫХ ГЛАГОЛОВ.

Comment: Зачем такое сложное правило: растерянный - растерянность. Ясно, что НН сохраняются перед суффиксом на гласную ОСТЬ.

Comment: _У вас: растеряться - растерянный (прич.)_ === Да, виноват. Сейчас поправлю!

Answer (score 2):

1) Разбор слова по составу:

Рас/тер/я/ть - рас/тер/я/нн/ый - рас/тер/я/нн/ость.

2) Словообразовательный разбор:

Растерянный (прич.) - растерянный (прил.) - растерянность.

Неморфологический способ образования прилагательного (переход из причастия в прилагательное, адъективация).

3) НН пишется в причастии (суффикс НН) и сохраняется в прилагательном, а также в существительном.